# Unable to receive form submissions on Netlify deploys

Tags: forms, gatsby, netlify

I am using a simple form that was taken from one of the Netlify related docs:

```
<form name="contact" action="/" method="post" data-netlify="true">

    <div className="field">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="dave"/>
    </div>
    <div className="field">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="email@email.com" />
    </div>
    <div className="field">
        <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>   
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" className="" />

</form>
```

In using `gatsby develop` and working with/submitting the form, things seem to work fine. I get no errors and get redirected to the home page as expected.

After deploying the site with Netlify and trying to submit the form, I get the following page error:

[image: netlify-form-error.PNG]

In my Netlify backend, the form appears in the console but I cannot/do not receive submissions.

I am using a barebones `gatsby-config.js`, only incorporating `gatsby-source-wordpress` and `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`.

I also tried adding `/no-cache=1` to form action.

Can anybody advise?

It might also be worth noting that I have coded my form as a component and am importing it into my footer as such. In that way, it may be imported multiple times on different pages as mentioned in point 3 of [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846768/netlify-form-submissions-are-blank).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I learned that because I'm using Gatsbyjs,  and Gatsby + Netlify = javascript forms, I needed to add another `input type="hidden"` to my form:

```
<form name="my-form" ... >
   <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="my-form" />
```

The documentation for this wasn't immediately clear but below are some links that address this:

- Here's a link to an article that pointed me to the answer: [How to
  Integrate Netlify’s Form Handling in a React App](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/)
- Here's another one if you're building in Vue: [How to Integrate
  Netlify Forms in a Vue App](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/07/how-to-integrate-netlify-forms-in-a-vue-app/)
- And all about [Netlify Forms](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any redirect method then you have to add **_redirects** file in your root folder and add paths to it so that redirect can work.

It's may be confusing but you can visit this [link](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/) for more help.